# Array Type Mismatches

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm a bit rusty with my VBA, especially with arrays. I have some code below that's goal is to

1. grab the values in a given range
2. remove any duplicates
3. remove some value based on criteria (ex: remove blanks, remove entries starting with 7, etc.)
4. I need the size of the final range or array to properly insert it in a sheet after

```
Function AllAddedParts(FullFilePath As String) As Variant
    
    Dim arrValues As Variant
    Dim arrUnikVals As String
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim src As Workbook
    
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(FullFilePath, True, True)
    
    ' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
    Dim iTotalRows As Integer
    TotalRows = src.Worksheets("Add - Cancel Report (EV6)").Range("D1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
   
      
    ' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK.
    Dim iCnt As Integer         ' COUNTER.
    Dim ArrDim As Long: ArrDim = 0
    
    arrValues = src.Worksheets("Add - Cancel Report (EV6)").Range("D4:D" & TotalRows)
    
  
    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src = Nothing
    
    ' Reove Duplicates
    arrUnikVals = RemoveDupesColl(arrValues)
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Then that calls this function:

```
Function RemoveDupesColl(MyArray As Variant) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrColl As New Collection
    Dim arrDummy As Variant
    Dim arrDummy1 As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    ReDim arrDummy1(LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray))
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:a66") = MyArray

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) 'convert to string
        arrDummy1(i) = CStr(MyArray(i)) '<------------------THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR, Type mismatch
    Next i
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each item In arrDummy1
       arrColl.Add item, item
    Next item
    Err.Clear
    ReDim arrDummy(LBound(MyArray) To arrColl.Count + LBound(MyArray) - 1)
    i = LBound(MyArray)
    For Each item In arrColl
       arrDummy(i) = item
       i = i + 1
    Next item
    RemoveDupesColl = arrDummy
End Function
```

I'm guessing it's due to how I declared ArrValues and MyArray? But I don;t know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `arrValues = src.Worksheets("Add - Cancel Report (EV6)").Range("D4:D" & TotalRows)` creates a 2D array not a 1D array. As such: `arrDummy1(i) = CStr(MyArray(i))` needs to be `arrDummy1(i) = CStr(MyArray(i,1))`

Comment: Well fk... was that simple. So whenever I load a range in a variant the array created is always 2D by default?

Comment: Yes unless the range is a single cell, in which case `.Value` doesn't give you an array.  NB an array derived from a range.Value is always 1-based (not the default zero-base for regular arrays)

Comment: The rest is not working well. It gives me an array with the same string repeated for all values int the array.
The goal was to remove all duplicate values.